# Show total checkbox count on multiple locations on the same page

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Im am using the following code to count the check boxes and display the total count and its working fine. But now i want to display the total count on two different locations on the same page, but it does not work. What am i doing wrong ?

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="E33" />A
    <input type="checkbox" name="E34" />B
    <input type="checkbox" name="E66" />C

    <p id="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>
    <p id="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>

    *also show total count inside the text input 
    <input type="text" id="result" name="total" placeholder="show total count"/>



<script>
showChecked();
function showChecked(){
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Total Number of Items Selected = " + document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
}
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick = function(){
  showChecked();
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you have 3 id="result". Id must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same `id` for both `result`. Change the `id` for the second one and set its value as well. You can also clean this up but I am sure that should get you going.

```js
showChecked();
function showChecked(){
   var length = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length,  
       text = "Total Number of Items Selected = ",
       results = document.getElementsByClassName("result"),
       total = 0

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(results, function(r){
       r.textContent = text + length
       total = total + length
   })
  
   document.getElementById("final").value = total;
}
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(i=>{
     i.onclick = function(){
     showChecked();
 }
});
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="E33" />A
    <input type="checkbox" name="E34" />B
    <input type="checkbox" name="E66" />C

    <p class="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>
    <p class="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>

    *also show total count inside the text input 
    <input type="text" id="final" name="total" placeholder="show total count"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Akrion but the total count is not showing inside the text input ?

Comment: Sorry skipped over that. Fixed it. You can rework this to be cleaner and nicer I just wanted to give you something quickly to get you going.

Comment: I updated it again to something more cleaner and less depended on the `result` ids. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="E33" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="E34" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="E66" />C

<p class="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>
<p class="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>

*also show total count inside the text input 
<input type="text" id="result" name="total" placeholder="show total count"/>
```

_

```
function showChecked() {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("result")].forEach(
    el => el.textContent = "Total Number of Items Selected = " + 
          document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put inputs in two different div groups

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    
 <div id="placeA">
  <input type="checkbox" name="E33" />A
  <input type="checkbox" name="E34" />B
  <input type="checkbox" name="E66" />C
 </div>
 
 <div id="placeB">
  <input type="checkbox" name="E37" />A
  <input type="checkbox" name="E38" />B
  <input type="checkbox" name="E69" />C
 </div>
 
    <p id="resultA">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>
    <p id="resultB">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>

    *also show total count inside the text input 
    <input type="text" id="result" name="total" placeholder="show total count"/>



<script>
showChecked();
function showChecked(){
 var countA = document.getElementById("placeA").querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
 document.getElementById("resultA").textContent = "Total Number of Items Selected = " + countA;
 
 var countB = document.getElementById("placeB").querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
 document.getElementById("resultB").textContent = "Total Number of Items Selected = " + countB;
 
 document.getElementById("result").value = countA + countB;
}
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick = function(){
  showChecked();
 }
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```